# Supress console output from chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

When troubleshooting my own javascript, I see console messages from my installed chrome extensions.  Is there any way to supress these messages?  I'd prefer to not see them as they clutter up the console output.

Comment: Temporarily disabling the other extensions is a quick and easy way.

Comment: Another quick and easy way is to use an incognito window.  You can give only your extension permission to run in incognito in the extensions page (chrome://extensions/) and then just open the site/whatever in incognito.

Comment: If the incognito tip had been a proper answer I would vote it (been there, done that myself). Another option is have a VM to host immaculate browsers for this.

Comment: MrMisterMan - I up voted your response, and will mark it as an answer if you have it as a response.   I like the idea of penalizing extension developers who deploy their product this way until Google offers a way to suppress these messages in installed instances.

Comment: @KyleB. of course, unless you need that extension :) And if you don't  need it, why not just remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporarily disabling the other extensions is a quick and easy way.